# API-based gaming platform which takes care of game execution

Tags: web-apps

**Summary**

I'm looking for some platform that are "reachable" through APIs and support a decent set of multiplayer games. Such platform should take care of the game execution and management (e.g. synchronization between players, turn-taking).

**What I need it for**

I need it to develop a web application (and hopefully a mobile version if supported by those platforms) in which, at some point (other details are unnecessary), the user must take a game against one or more other players.

**Features needed**

The game will ideally be "set-up" from the application side (e.g. participants and any other configuration if the game requires it), the execution will then be delegated to the platform and, at the end of the game, I will only know statistics about it, in order to proceed with my flow.

Classical games (e.g. tic-tac-toe, chess) could be enough but, of course, a more complete list of possibility would be better.

**Budget**
Not unlimited, but I can surely evaluate paid solutions.

I'm sorry if I couldn't explain what I'm looking for in an efficient way, I hope that my needs are clear. I will answer any question if some clarifications are needed.

Thanks

Comment: Is it a real-time game or turn-based?

Comment: It would be better if real time, as the games shouldn't be too complex. But a turn-based solution could be acceptable for my use-case.